# Nextcord.py scheduled guild events str doesn't have attribute value

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I'm attempting to make a discord events bot using nextcord.py/dpy and the discord official events but I'm having trouble with **entity_type** as its giving me an error **type error str doesn't have attribute value** and im confused about this

**here is my command**

```
@client.command(name='rp' ,help= 'creates an event')
async def rp(ctx, name=None, time =None, reason = None):
  #external = 
  channel = nextcord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name = 'roleplay-sessions')
  await ctx.guild.create_scheduled_event(name=name, channel = channel, start_time = time, description = reason, entity_type = 'external')
```

any help would be awesome as its been 13 hours and my head hurts thanks

Answer (score 0):

[nextcord doc](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_scheduled_event#nextcord.ScheduledEventEntityType)

you need to use:

```
entity_type = nextcord.ScheduledEventEntityType.external
```

also:

- channel needs to be a voice_channel
- all args are required
- start_time needs to be in the future
- for start_time & end_time use timezone.utc

Type.external snippet

```
@client.command()
async def rp(ctx):
    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=10)
    tomorrow = now + timedelta(days=1)
    await ctx.guild.create_scheduled_event(
        name="roleplay-sessions",
        privacy_level = nextcord.ScheduledEventPrivacyLevel.guild_only, # optional
        metadata = nextcord.EntityMetadata(location='roleplay-sessions'),
        start_time = now,
        end_time = tomorrow,
        description = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
        entity_type = nextcord.ScheduledEventEntityType.external
        )
```

Type.voice snippet

```
@client.command()
async def rp(ctx):
    channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID)) # voice_channel
    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=10)
    await ctx.guild.create_scheduled_event(
        name="roleplay-sessions",
        channel = channel,
        privacy_level = nextcord.ScheduledEventPrivacyLevel.guild_only, # optional
        start_time = now,
        description = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
        entity_type = nextcord.ScheduledEventEntityType.voice
        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Flekay what if i want to have a customizable start time say for instance i have the user say it was at 3 pm today instead of now how would i do that

Comment: @TheRavenSeb check out datetime.strptime() https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
otherwise you have to write your own class